# Filter Partition Before Reading Hive table (Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

Currently I'm trying to filter a Hive table by the latest date_processed.

The table is partitioned by.

System
date_processed 
Region

The only way I've managed to filter it, is by doing a join query:

```
query = "select * from contracts_table as a join (select (max(date_processed) as maximum from contract_table as b) on a.date_processed = b.maximum"
```

This way is really time consuming, as I have to do the same procedure for 25 tables.

Any one Knows a way to read directly the latest loaded partition of a table in Spark <1.6

This is the method I'm using to read.

```
public static DataFrame loadAndFilter (String query)
{
        return SparkContextSingleton.getHiveContext().sql(+query);
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe with all table partitions can be received by:

```
val partitionsDF = hiveContext.sql("show partitions TABLE_NAME")
```

Values can be parsed, for get max value.

Comment: I think this could work and improve performance, but actually does not entirely solve the problem, as you steel need to load 20 new DataFrames, calculate the max, and then filter the other tables....Eitherway ill try it, and see how's the performance. Thanks!