# How get partitions from spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

There is a `DataFrame` and it is needed to perform join from that DataFrame with another one. To reduce data it is needed to select data with equals partitions look at code:

```
 // get partition values (like 2017-01-01, 2017-01-02 etc)
val partitionValues = leftDataFrame.someFunctionHere()
rightDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("view")
//approximative syntax here
val rightDataFrameReduced = sparkSession
    .sql(s"select * from view where my_partition_col IN ($partitionValues)") 
rightDataFrameReduced.createOrReplaceTempView("right_df")
leftDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("left_df")    
//approximative syntax here
sparkSession.sql(s"select * from view right_df joint left_df ON right_df.id = left_df.id")
```

So the question is - what to used instead of `leftDataFrame.someFunctionHere()` to get partition values and avoid full recods scan?

Comment: For Hive table such approach can be used:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222939/filter-partition-before-reading-hive-table-spark/46228130#46228130

Comment: if dataframe is partitioned by e.g. a String "date", do `leftDataFrame.select($"date").distinct.as[String].collect`

Comment: You mean "partitions" in the sense of Spark SQL's Dataset not Spark Core's RDD, correct? Use `Catalog` to get the table metadata. But Spark SQL does it under the covers, really.